# MySQL Query to get only one entry per interval from database

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with this structure and some sample values:

```
ID | created | value | person
1  |  1      |   5   | 1
2  |  2      |   2   | 2
3  |  3      |   3   | 3
4  |  4      |   5   | 1
5  |  5      |   1   | 2
6  |  6      |   32  | 3
7  |  7      |   9   | 1
8  |  8      |   34  | 2
10 |  9      |   25  | 3
11 |  11     |   53  | 1
12 |  12     |   52  | 2
13 |  13     |   15  | 3
... etc
```

The created column will have timestamps. I.e. A number like "1555073978". I just made it incremental to demonstrate that the timestamps will rarely be the same.

So values are stored per person with creation times. Values are added every minute. After a week, this table is quite big. So when I do a query to draw a graph, PHP run's out of memory because the dataset is so huge.

So what I am looking for, is an easy way to do a query on a table like this, so that I get values in smaller intervals.

How would I query this table, so that I get:
 - only one value per person per interval
 - where interval should be 15 mins, 30 mins, 60 mins etc (i.e. a parameter in the query)

I've started with an approach but don't want to spend too much time, in case i am missing a much easier way. My way involves converting the timestamp to YEAR-MONTH-DAY-HOUR, but this will only work for hourly. I am also struggling to make sure that the query returns the MOST RECENT entry PER PERSON for that hour.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do minutes relate to any of the columns in your table?

Comment: which data type is exactly the column created ?? an which value you want  ..for each person  a sum()  . an avg()  ??

Comment: Data type = int.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your created  column is a timestamp and you want the max value for person every each 15 minutes you could try

```
select  person, max(value)
from my_table 
group by person, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created )/(15 * 60))
```

but if you dont need unix_timestamp

then

```
group by person, FLOOR(created /(15 * 60))
```

If you want the most  recent values for person and interval  then you could use

```
select  * from my_table m 
inner join  (
  select  person, max(created) max_created 
  from my_table 
  group by person, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created )/(15 * 60))
) t on t.person = m.person and t.max_created  = m.created
```

Comment: It is already a unix timestamp so no need for unix_timestamp. it should be FLOOR(created / 900) * 900

Comment: This looks so simple and makes my idea look insane. I'll test this and report back.

Comment: One issue I am already seeing is that I don't necessarily want the "max". Essentially it shouldnt matter, but it would be a little better if it's the most recent entry from that period, not the highest.

Comment: for each query you must define your goal  .. the last value  is the row  that match a max  value ..in join with the value   ..  but this seems another question  to me .. you question is how filter the value  for created  column  time  interval

Comment: anyway answer  updated .. with a query for most recent value by inteval